# Professor stopped replying about internship

Tags: internship

I emailed a professor about a research internship to which he replied saying that I could work under him,  but without any payment. He had earlier mentioned that he would be more interested if I was doing a PhD program instead of an internship. I then sent him two mails in which I conveyed that I wanted to do the internship and would fund it myself,  and enquire if it would be possible to obtain accommodation on campus itself. He hasnt replied to those mails and it's been ten days. Should I mail him again or is it a no? I'm confused,  and if I have to reply to him, what should I say?

Answer (score 3):

It's summer (in the northern hemisphere), and many people take vacations or travel to conferences in summer, during which it may not be possible to answer emails.  So don't assume the professor is intentionally ignoring you.  If you haven't heard anything in another week or two, you could try again.